# JSON representation conversion

Tags: javascript, json

I am a beginner at javascript, I am trying to generate an icicle graph using my JSON. The form my JSON is in is similar to the example seen at the bottom of the page here

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I want my JSON to be represented the way it is at the bottom of the example here

```
   {
  "flare": {
    "analytics": {
      "cluster": {
        "AgglomerativeCluster": 3938,
        "CommunityStructure": 3812,
        "HierarchicalCluster": 6714,
        "MergeEdge": 743
      },
      "graph": {
        "BetweennessCentrality": 3534,
        "LinkDistance": 5731,
        "MaxFlowMinCut": 7840,
        "ShortestPaths": 5914,
        "SpanningTree": 3416
      },
      "optimization": {
        "AspectRatioBanker": 7074
      }
    },
    "animate": {
      "Easing": 17010,
      "FunctionSequence": 5842,
      "interpolate": {
        "ArrayInterpolator": 1983,
        "ColorInterpolator": 2047,
        "DateInterpolator": 1375,
        "Interpolator": 8746,
        "MatrixInterpolator": 2202,
        "NumberInterpolator": 1382,
        "ObjectInterpolator": 1629,
        "PointInterpolator": 1675,
        "RectangleInterpolator": 2042
      },
      "ISchedulable": 1041,
      "Parallel": 5176,
      "Pause": 449,
      "Scheduler": 5593,
      "Sequence": 5534,
      "Transition": 9201,
      "Transitioner": 19975,
      "TransitionEvent": 1116,
      "Tween": 6006
    },
    "data": {
      "converters": {
        "Converters": 721,
        "DelimitedTextConverter": 4294,
        "GraphMLConverter": 9800,
        "IDataConverter": 1314,
        "JSONConverter": 2220
      },
      "DataField": 1759,
      "DataSchema": 2165,
      "DataSet": 586,
      "DataSource": 3331,
      "DataTable": 772,
      "DataUtil": 3322
    },
    "display": {
      "DirtySprite": 8833,
      "LineSprite": 1732,
      "RectSprite": 3623,
      "TextSprite": 10066
    },
    "flex": {
      "FlareVis": 4116
    },
    "physics": {
      "DragForce": 1082,
      "GravityForce": 1336,
      "IForce": 319,
      "NBodyForce": 10498,
      "Particle": 2822,
      "Simulation": 9983,
      "Spring": 2213,
      "SpringForce": 1681
    },
    "query": {
      "AggregateExpression": 1616,
      "And": 1027,
      "Arithmetic": 3891,
      "Average": 891,
      "BinaryExpression": 2893,
      "Comparison": 5103,
      "CompositeExpression": 3677,
      "Count": 781,
      "DateUtil": 4141,
      "Distinct": 933,
      "Expression": 5130,
      "ExpressionIterator": 3617,
      "Fn": 3240,
      "If": 2732,
      "IsA": 2039,
      "Literal": 1214,
      "Match": 3748,
      "Maximum": 843,
      "methods": {
        "add": 593,
        "and": 330,
        "average": 287,
        "count": 277,
        "distinct": 292,
        "div": 595,
        "eq": 594,
        "fn": 460,
        "gt": 603,
        "gte": 625,
        "iff": 748,
        "isa": 461,
        "lt": 597,
        "lte": 619,
        "max": 283,
        "min": 283,
        "mod": 591,
        "mul": 603,
        "neq": 599,
        "not": 386,
        "or": 323,
        "orderby": 307,
        "range": 772,
        "select": 296,
        "stddev": 363,
        "sub": 600,
        "sum": 280,
        "update": 307,
        "variance": 335,
        "where": 299,
        "xor": 354,
        "_": 264
      },
      "Minimum": 843,
      "Not": 1554,
      "Or": 970,
      "Query": 13896,
      "Range": 1594,
      "StringUtil": 4130,
      "Sum": 791,
      "Variable": 1124,
      "Variance": 1876,
      "Xor": 1101
    },
    "scale": {
      "IScaleMap": 2105,
      "LinearScale": 1316,
      "LogScale": 3151,
      "OrdinalScale": 3770,
      "QuantileScale": 2435,
      "QuantitativeScale": 4839,
      "RootScale": 1756,
      "Scale": 4268,
      "ScaleType": 1821,
      "TimeScale": 5833
    },
    "util": {
      "Arrays": 8258,
      "Colors": 10001,
      "Dates": 8217,
      "Displays": 12555,
      "Filter": 2324,
      "Geometry": 10993,
      "heap": {
        "FibonacciHeap": 9354,
        "HeapNode": 1233
      },
      "IEvaluable": 335,
      "IPredicate": 383,
      "IValueProxy": 874,
      "math": {
        "DenseMatrix": 3165,
        "IMatrix": 2815,
        "SparseMatrix": 3366
      },
      "Maths": 17705,
      "Orientation": 1486,
      "palette": {
        "ColorPalette": 6367,
        "Palette": 1229,
        "ShapePalette": 2059,
        "SizePalette": 2291
      },
      "Property": 5559,
      "Shapes": 19118,
      "Sort": 6887,
      "Stats": 6557,
      "Strings": 22026
    },
    "vis": {
      "axis": {
        "Axes": 1302,
        "Axis": 24593,
        "AxisGridLine": 652,
        "AxisLabel": 636,
        "CartesianAxes": 6703
      },
      "controls": {
        "AnchorControl": 2138,
        "ClickControl": 3824,
        "Control": 1353,
        "ControlList": 4665,
        "DragControl": 2649,
        "ExpandControl": 2832,
        "HoverControl": 4896,
        "IControl": 763,
        "PanZoomControl": 5222,
        "SelectionControl": 7862,
        "TooltipControl": 8435
      },
      "data": {
        "Data": 20544,
        "DataList": 19788,
        "DataSprite": 10349,
        "EdgeSprite": 3301,
        "NodeSprite": 19382,
        "render": {
          "ArrowType": 698,
          "EdgeRenderer": 5569,
          "IRenderer": 353,
          "ShapeRenderer": 2247
        },
        "ScaleBinding": 11275,
        "Tree": 7147,
        "TreeBuilder": 9930
      },
      "events": {
        "DataEvent": 2313,
        "SelectionEvent": 1880,
        "TooltipEvent": 1701,
        "VisualizationEvent": 1117
      },
      "legend": {
        "Legend": 20859,
        "LegendItem": 4614,
        "LegendRange": 10530
      },
      "operator": {
        "distortion": {
          "BifocalDistortion": 4461,
          "Distortion": 6314,
          "FisheyeDistortion": 3444
        },
        "encoder": {
          "ColorEncoder": 3179,
          "Encoder": 4060,
          "PropertyEncoder": 4138,
          "ShapeEncoder": 1690,
          "SizeEncoder": 1830
        },
        "filter": {
          "FisheyeTreeFilter": 5219,
          "GraphDistanceFilter": 3165,
          "VisibilityFilter": 3509
        },
        "IOperator": 1286,
        "label": {
          "Labeler": 9956,
          "RadialLabeler": 3899,
          "StackedAreaLabeler": 3202
        },
        "layout": {
          "AxisLayout": 6725,
          "BundledEdgeRouter": 3727,
          "CircleLayout": 9317,
          "CirclePackingLayout": 12003,
          "DendrogramLayout": 4853,
          "ForceDirectedLayout": 8411,
          "IcicleTreeLayout": 4864,
          "IndentedTreeLayout": 3174,
          "Layout": 7881,
          "NodeLinkTreeLayout": 12870,
          "PieLayout": 2728,
          "RadialTreeLayout": 12348,
          "RandomLayout": 870,
          "StackedAreaLayout": 9121,
          "TreeMapLayout": 9191
        },
        "Operator": 2490,
        "OperatorList": 5248,
        "OperatorSequence": 4190,
        "OperatorSwitch": 2581,
        "SortOperator": 2023
      },
      "Visualization": 16540
    }
  }
}
```

So that I can use that icicle graph instead. Is there a way to accomplish this task without doing it manually?

I want to use this javascript code, which will only work with the second JSON format/representation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

rect {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="breadcrumb"></div>
<div id="icicle"></div>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, height]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var vis = d3.select('#icicle').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var partition = d3.partition()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(0)
    .round(true);

// Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
var b = {
  w: 150, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
};

var rect = vis.selectAll("rect");
var fo = vis.selectAll("foreignObject");
var totalSize=0;

d3.json("readme.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(d3.entries(root)[0], function(d) {
      return d3.entries(d.value)
    })
    .sum(function(d) { return d.value })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  partition(root);

  //add breadcrumb
  initializeBreadcrumbTrail();
  var percentage = 100;
      var percentageString = percentage + "%";

      d3.select("#percentage")
          .text(percentageString);

      d3.select("#explanation")
          .style("visibility", "");

      var sequenceArray = root.ancestors().reverse();
      //sequenceArray.shift(); // remove root node from the array
      updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

  rect = rect
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.key); })
      .on("click", clicked);

    fo = fo
        .data(root.descendants())
        .enter().append("foreignObject")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0; })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
     .style("cursor", "pointer")
     .text(function(d) { return d.data.key})
     .on("click", clicked);

     //get total size from rect
    totalSize = rect.node().__data__.value;
});

function clicked(d) {

    x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
    y.domain([d.y0, height]).range([d.depth ? 20 : 0, height]);

    rect.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x0); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y1) - y(d.y0); });

      fo.transition()
        .duration(750)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x0); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1-d.x0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y1-d.y0); });

      // code to update the BreadcrumbTrail();
    var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
      var percentageString = percentage + "%";
      if (percentage < 0.1) {
        percentageString = "< 0.1%";
      }

      d3.select("#percentage")
          .text(percentageString);

      d3.select("#explanation")
          .style("visibility", "");

      var sequenceArray = d.ancestors().reverse();
      //sequenceArray.shift(); // remove root node from the array
      updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#breadcrumb").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");

      // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var trail = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.data.key + d.depth; });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  trail.exit().remove();

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = trail.enter().append("g");

  entering.append("polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.key); });

  entering.append("text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; });

  // Merge enter and update selections; set position for all nodes.
  entering.merge(trail).attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

}

</script>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant info in the post.

Comment: I am sorry, I am a beginner with JSON/Javascript, what information am I missing?

Comment: Whatever is in the links. We shouldn't have to go off-site to help.

Comment: Include code (relevant javascript, html, etc) you are currently attempting to use

Comment: I added, the JSON representations, and the code I want to use. I apologize for posting with missing information.

Comment: @JonD How are you generating the 1st JSON?

Comment: I am using d3_nest package in R on a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is pretty simple — just `name`, `size`, and `children`, and `size`/`children` are mutually exclusive, you can make a simple function that creates an object based on `name` and `size` an then recursively call that on the children using `Object.assign` to help.

```js
let obj = {"name": "flare","children": [{"name": "analytics","children": [{"name": "cluster","children": [{"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},{"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},{"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},{"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}]},{"name": "graph","children": [{"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},{"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},{"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},{"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},{"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}]},{"name": "optimization","children": [{"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}]}]},{"name": "animate","children": [{"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},{"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},{"name": "interpolate","children": [{"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},{"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},{"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},{"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},{"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},{"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},{"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},{"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},{"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}]},{"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},{"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},{"name": "Pause", "size": 449},{"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},{"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},{"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},{"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},{"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},{"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}]},{"name": "data","children": [{"name": "converters","children": [{"name": "Converters", "size": 721},{"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},{"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},{"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},{"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}]},{"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},{"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},{"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},{"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},{"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},{"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}]},{"name": "display","children": [{"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},{"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},{"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},{"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}]},{"name": "flex","children": [{"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}]},{"name": "physics","children": [{"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},{"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},{"name": "IForce", "size": 319},{"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},{"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},{"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},{"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},{"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}]},{"name": "query","children": [{"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},{"name": "And", "size": 1027},{"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},{"name": "Average", "size": 891},{"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},{"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},{"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},{"name": "Count", "size": 781},{"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},{"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},{"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},{"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},{"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},{"name": "If", "size": 2732},{"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},{"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},{"name": "Match", "size": 3748},{"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},{"name": "methods","children": [{"name": "add", "size": 593},{"name": "and", "size": 330},{"name": "average", "size": 287},{"name": "count", "size": 277},{"name": "distinct", "size": 292},{"name": "div", "size": 595},{"name": "eq", "size": 594},{"name": "fn", "size": 460},{"name": "gt", "size": 603},{"name": "gte", "size": 625},{"name": "iff", "size": 748},{"name": "isa", "size": 461},{"name": "lt", "size": 597},{"name": "lte", "size": 619},{"name": "max", "size": 283},{"name": "min", "size": 283},{"name": "mod", "size": 591},{"name": "mul", "size": 603},{"name": "neq", "size": 599},{"name": "not", "size": 386},{"name": "or", "size": 323},{"name": "orderby", "size": 307},{"name": "range", "size": 772},{"name": "select", "size": 296},{"name": "stddev", "size": 363},{"name": "sub", "size": 600},{"name": "sum", "size": 280},{"name": "update", "size": 307},{"name": "variance", "size": 335},{"name": "where", "size": 299},{"name": "xor", "size": 354},{"name": "_", "size": 264}]},{"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},{"name": "Not", "size": 1554},{"name": "Or", "size": 970},{"name": "Query", "size": 13896},{"name": "Range", "size": 1594},{"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},{"name": "Sum", "size": 791},{"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},{"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},{"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}]},{"name": "scale","children": [{"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},{"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},{"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},{"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},{"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},{"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},{"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},{"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},{"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},{"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}]},{"name": "util","children": [{"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},{"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},{"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},{"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},{"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},{"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},{"name": "heap","children": [{"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},{"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}]},{"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},{"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},{"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},{"name": "math","children": [{"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},{"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},{"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}]},{"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},{"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},{"name": "palette","children": [{"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},{"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},{"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},{"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}]},{"name": "Property", "size": 5559},{"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},{"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},{"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},{"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}]},{"name": "vis","children": [{"name": "axis","children": [{"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},{"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},{"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},{"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},{"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}]},{"name": "controls","children": [{"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},{"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},{"name": "Control", "size": 1353},{"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},{"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},{"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},{"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},{"name": "IControl", "size": 763},{"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},{"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},{"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}]},{"name": "data","children": [{"name": "Data", "size": 20544},{"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},{"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},{"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},{"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},{"name": "render","children": [{"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},{"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},{"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},{"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}]},{"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},{"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},{"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}]},{"name": "events","children": [{"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},{"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},{"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},{"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}]},{"name": "legend","children": [{"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},{"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},{"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}]},{"name": "operator","children": [{"name": "distortion","children": [{"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},{"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},{"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}]},{"name": "encoder","children": [{"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},{"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},{"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},{"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},{"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}]},{"name": "filter","children": [{"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},{"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},{"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}]},{"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},{"name": "label","children": [{"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},{"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},{"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}]},{"name": "layout","children": [{"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},{"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},{"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},{"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},{"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},{"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},{"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},{"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},{"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},{"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},{"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},{"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},{"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},{"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},{"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}]},{"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},{"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},{"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},{"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},{"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}]},{"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}]}]}

function convertObject(obj){
    let ch
    if (obj.children) {
       ch = obj.children.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, convertObject(c)), {})
    }
    return {[obj.name]: (obj.size || ch)}
}
console.log(convertObject(obj))
```

The way this works: `convertObject` takes an object and returns an object with a `name` property. If the `obj` passed in has a `size` the returned object will just be `{obj.name: obj.size}`. If the passed in object has a children property, it will call `convertObject` with each child. Each of those calls will return an object and `reduce` will merge them all into one object, which we call `ch` above. In the cases where there are children the `converObject` function returns an object in the form `{object.name, ch}`.

It's understandable that this can be a little hard to wrap your head around — recursive functions take a little getting used to.

Comment: Mark, this is working in the snippet but I can't get it to run in javascript on my end. I also tried moving it into jsfiddle but I couldn't get an output.

Comment: @JonD Hmm, without a little more info, it's hard to know why. Have you already parsed your JSON with something like `let obj = JSON.parse(json_string)`? Maybe you could leave a link to the non-working jsfiddle.

Comment: I have not parsed my JSON, I just copied my JSON into let obj =
I also tried copying your example exactly as it is and moving it into jsfiddle and it didn't work there either.

Comment: jsfiddle says that in the return function ch is out of scope. Does this code use a library like vue or is it pure javascript?

Comment: Okay. So you need to parse you json first. The function is expecting a javascript object, which you'll get when you parse it. It's working on jsfiddle, but the console.log doesn't write to jsfiddle's output, you'll need to look in the browser console. I changed the variable declaration so jsfiddle's linter doesn't complain. Here's a fiddle that appends it to the output: http://jsfiddle.net/njtLc3x8/4/

Comment: Mark can you explain how the code you wrote is working? My JSONs children have their own children and this code is not returning them. It is only returning the top level children.

Comment: @JonD, I'm not sure I follow. `flare` has children `analytics` and `graph`. `analytics` has children `cluster` and `cluster` has 4 other children. These are all in the hierarchy and it's is how your example is. What data is missing? The code works by taking all the children in an object and making them properties base on the child's name and then recursively doing it for all the children of the children, etc.

Comment: Yes, the code works perfectly. But I am just trying to understand how it works so I can apply it to a case where children have their own children. Right now, if I apply your code to the new case, I only get back the first child. Please don't misunderstand the code works perfectly and the answer is perfect to the question I asked.

Comment: @JonD I added some explanation. It's actually hard to explain recursion without drawing the steps out. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it now. So regardless of how many children a child has this function should, if a size is available, return {obj.name, obj.size}. But for some reason it is not returning all the children in this example http://jsfiddle.net/njtLc3x8/12/

Comment: Hmm, so in that example the objects can have both size and children at the same time. So a lot of the children will get left off (in the case where there's also a size). You should be able to fiddle with the test to determine which one you want when both exist.

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying now. So, I can not keep both of them? I have to choose one or the other?